# jQuery Date Picker Pick Year First and then Month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What changes are needed to show the Years dropdown first and then the months dropdown as second field in jQuery so users can select which year they are born and then select the month in that year. We still want to restrict that calendar cannot display date greater than today.

If user selects 2011, they should not be allowed to select date greater than today.

Comment: Why don't you use selects instead?

Comment: Right now calendar object has select fields. But it has month first. Since month is first box it is not showing dec since year is default to 2011.this is nov so users are confused why dec is not showing up. If they change year to 2010 then all months are shown. Hope I explained it.

Answer (score 15):

I was looking for this also and got here but no solution so I get into jquery-ui.custom.min.js and found the an option. Its as below. Hope it helps although its a bit late..

```
$( "#datepicker_id" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat:'mm-dd-yy',
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    showMonthAfterYear: true, //this is what you are looking for
    maxDate:0
});
```

But if you found that already you should have posted it here :)

Answer (score 2):

For this simple use below line:

```
startView: 2
```

And add below line to prevent to select date greater than today:

```
endDate: new Date(),
```

Comment: thnx buddy "startView: 2" worked for me