# Swap month/year select list placement in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to swap the placement of the month/year select elements in a datepicker that has the changeYear and changeMonth options enabled.

By default the order of appearance is month then year and I want year then month.

Run the code snippet below to see why:

```js
$( "#picker" ).datepicker({
            maxDate: 'today',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            minDate: "01/01/1939",
            stepMonths:12,
            yearRange: "1939:" + new Date().getFullYear()
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<form>


 
<div><b>How do I swap the month/year select list placement?</b></div>
  
Birthdate: <input type="text" name="picker" id="picker" value="" />
  
 <ol>
  <li>Click the input above to open the datepicker.</li>
  <li>Click on the month select list to view the select options available.</li>
<li>Notice that it only shows up to the current month?  This is confusing to users.</li>
<li>Change the year to any previous one.<li>
 <li>Now select a month,  they are all there.</li>
<li>In our world of left to right processing, in this case, it makes sense to have the year appear first followed by the month.</li>
</ol>  
  
 </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Date Picker Pick Year First and then Month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299266/jquery-date-picker-pick-year-first-and-then-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply float the month and year to the right with CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month, 
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year { float: right; }
```

Or as the duplicate answer provides: use the [option](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showMonthAfterYear) `showMonthAfterYear: true`